# How to get response status in GraphQL using node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, typescript, graphql

**In my node js code**

```
var express_graphql = require('express-graphql');
var { buildSchema } = require('graphql');

var schema = buildSchema(`
    type Query {      
        getCandidateKey(email  : String): GetCandidateKey
    }

 type GetCandidateKey{
        CandidateID : Int
    }
`);
```

here i am executing the stored procedure

```
var GetCandidateKey = async function (args) {
    let email = args.email
    let query = "exec getCandidateKey @EmailID='" + email + "';"; //executing stored procedures
    const pool = await poolPromise
    const result = await pool.request().query(query)
    return result.recordset[0]
}
```

Root resolver

```
var root = {
    getCandidateKey: GetCandidateKey,
};
```

Create an express server and a GraphQL endpoint

```
  app.use('/graphql', express_graphql({
        schema: schema,
        rootValue: root,
        graphiql: true
    }));
```

**The result i am getting**

[image]

**The result i want if query successfully execute**

```
{
 "status" : "success"
  "data": {
    "getCandidateKey": {
      "CandidateID": 56
    }
  }
}
```

**For any error**

```
    {
     "status" : "error"   //for throwing error
      "data": null    
    }
```

P.S  I am new to GraphQL and SQL Server.

Comment: Here is a good solution. https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-request
It works fairly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify this function so that it'll send the required object as the response.

```
var GetCandidateKey = async function (args) {
    try {
        let email = args.email
        let query = "exec getCandidateKey @EmailID='" + email + "';"; //executing stored procedures
        const pool = await poolPromise
        const result = await pool.request().query(query)
        return {
            status: 'success',
            data: result.recordset[0]
        };
    } catch (e) {
        return {
            status: 'error',
            data: null
        };
    }
}
```

And also change the GraphQL types as needed.

**Update**

You can use the following schema:

```
var schema = buildSchema(`
    type Query {      
        getCandidateKey(email  : String): CandidateResponse
    }

    type CandidateResponse {
        status: String!
        data: GetCandidateKey
    }

    type GetCandidateKey {
        CandidateID : Int
    }
`);
```

Comment: thanks for help but not getting the desired result.

Comment: i have changed my code according to your answer but there is no key  status showed in response also not getting candidateID in response. Here is the response i am getting after changing my code.{
  "data": {
    "getCandidateKey": {
      "CandidateID": null
    }
  }
}

Comment: @amanraj - Did you also modify the graphql types as required?

Comment: i haven't modified anything only changed GetCandidateKey given by you.

Comment: @amanraj - Now that your function returns a different object you should also change the type in the graphql schema, see my updated answer.